# How to open a new component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am creating a dashboard in React using Typescript and Material UI which has months and a corresponding value shown besides the months. For this, I am using a React component that I have created "Dashboard". Upon clicking a particular month, I want to open another view (component) to show the user some different information. How can I do that? This is the code of my component till now. Specifically I would like to know how to update the `handleMonthClick` method to open a new view when a month is selected.

```
import React from 'react';
import MonthCard from './MonthCard';

const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
  const months = [
    { month: 'January', passRate: 80 },
    { month: 'February', passRate: 75 },
    // Add more months as needed
  ];

  const handleMonthClick = (month: string) => {
    console.log(`Clicked on ${month}`);
    // You can add more logic here
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      {months.map((m) => (
        <MonthCard
          key={m.month}
          month={m.month}
          passRate={m.passRate}
          onClick={() => handleMonthClick(m.month)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: What does "open in a new view" mean specifically *to you*? Please [edit] to clarify what you are trying to accomplish and what any specific issue or problem is. See [mcve]. See also [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for additional tips to improve the quality of your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a state variable, set that state variable to the selected month, and then render some other component based on the month that is selected.

For example:

```js
const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
  const [selectedMonth, setSelectedMonth] = useState(null);

  const months = [
    { month: 'January', passRate: 80 },
    { month: 'February', passRate: 75 },
    // Add more months as needed
  ];

  const handleMonthClick = (month: string) => {
    console.log(`Clicked on ${month}`);
    setSelectedMonth(month);
    // You can add more logic here
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      {months.map((m) => (
        <MonthCard
          key={m.month}
          month={m.month}
          passRate={m.passRate}
          onClick={() => handleMonthClick(m.month)}
        />
      ))}

      {selectedMonth && <MyMonthDisplay month={selectedMonth} />}

    </div>
  );
};
```

Now create a new component `MyMonthDisplay.jsx` that displays information for the passed in `month` parameter.

Comment: But that will show both month card along with the new component rigght? I wanted to open a new page altogether by means of that component.

Comment: Also, the user should be able to go back to the current page to select a different month by some means (such as clicking the back arrow on the webpage)

Comment: So then you would likely want to use a Router (e.g. React Router) in React where you would navigate to something like `<Navigate to={"/showMonth/" + m.month} />` and have a `<Route>` defined for `/showMonth/:monthName`

Comment: will I have to define a route for each month? or can pass the new component to the route with month as a prop?

Comment: No, you would define a single route that uses a parameter: `/showMonth/:monthName`.  In the component that you render for that Route, you would use `useParams()` to get the value of `monthName`, and then use the monthName to determine what to show.  In React Router, any path segment that begins with a colon (`:`) is considered a "parameter".  So `/foo/:a/:b/:c` would define 3 possible parameters (`a`, `b`, and `c`) and if you navigate to `/foo/11/22/33` then `a === 11`, `b === 22` and `c === 33` based on the values you'd get from `useParams()`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can easily do that and get the desired functionality mentioned in the comments (having the new component replace the entire screen)

Below is code to do this with all the components in a single file(for example purposes), **you can copy and paste this into a component folder to use it anywhere**, and refer to it to update your code! (I added some super basic styles/css to make it an easier UI)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

//first create type and months const (these normally go in a helper file)
type MonthModel = {
  month: string;
  passRate: number;
};
const months:MonthModel[] = [
  { month: "January", passRate: 80 },
  { month: "February", passRate: 75 },
];


//create MonthCard component for each item in the list (normally type and corresponding component goes in their own file
type MonthCardProps = {
  onClick: () => void;
  m: MonthModel;
};
const MonthCard = ({ onClick, m }: MonthCardProps) => {
  console.log("empty but with access to:", m);
  return (
    <div
      onClick={onClick}
      style={{
        width: "25%",
        backgroundColor: "darkviolet",
        color: "white",
        cursor: "pointer",
      }}
    >
      {m.month}
      {m.passRate}
    </div>
  );
};

//create MonthDetailPanel that we can toggle with changing data (again, it should go in its own file with type.)
type MonthDetailPanelProps = {
  isOpen: boolean;
  month?: string;
  passRate?: number;
  handleClose: () => void;
};
const MonthDetailPanel = ({
  month,
  passRate,
  handleClose,
}: MonthDetailPanelProps) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <h1>Full Screen Swap</h1>
      <p>
        Data: {month}&nbsp;{passRate}
      </p>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "200px",
          backgroundColor: "darkblue",
          color: "white",
          height: "50px",
          cursor: "pointer",
        }}
        onClick={handleClose}
      >
        <h4>Click to close.</h4>
      </div>
      <h5>Date Dashboard</h5>
    </div>
  );
};


//main Dashboard component (parent component/file)
export const Dashboard: React.FC = () => {
  const [showDetailPanel, setShowDetailPanel] = useState<{
    isOpen: boolean;
    month?: string;
    passRate?: number;
  }>({ isOpen: false });
  let i = 0;

  return showDetailPanel.isOpen === false ? (
    <div>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100%",
        }}
      >
        {months.map((m) => {
          i = i + 1; //make sure each child has unique key
          return (
            <div
              key={`item ${i}`}
              style={{
                padding: "10px",
                width: "100%",
                display: "flex",
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center",
                flexDirection: "column",
              }}
            >
              <MonthCard
                onClick={() =>
                  setShowDetailPanel(() => {
                    return {
                      isOpen: true,
                      month: m.month,
                      passRate: m.passRate,
                    };
                  })
                }
                m={m}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <MonthDetailPanel
      {...showDetailPanel}
      handleClose={() =>
        setShowDetailPanel((prev) => {
          return { ...prev, isOpen: false };
        })
      }
    />
  );
};
```

let me know if you have any questions, if you're using tsx this should work on copy-paste, no extra libs were used